# Case sensitive WHERE in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have to import data from a paradox database into a newly created WPF / SQL-Server application. I have sucessfully imported the necessary paradox-data into Access and now are writing a utility that converts the the data and imports it into SQL Server.

Now I have the problem that the paradox primary-keys seem to be case sensitive. This leads to the proplem that I have records with a Primary Key "Au" and other recors with the primary Key "AU" and they are not the same.

Now **I search for a possibility to write Update scripts in Access** so that I can write

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET [PKFIELD]="Au1" WHERE [PKFIELD]='Au'
```

**that only affects the rows with [PKFIELD]='Au' and not the rows with [PKFIELD]='AU'**

Is there a function I can use for this or how can I achieve this.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is definitively about programming. Please make a comment if you downvote, so that the post owner knows what he has done false. If it is the fact that I have found the answer myself, would you recommend that I delete the question? I think for another person searching for the same thing, this post would be helpfull, that's why I posted the solution and did not delete the post. However I don't know if this is a no go on SO. Please inform me about that.

Comment: It is a useful question as far as I can see, and SO is a wiki, not a question and answer forum, so there is no reason why you should not ask a question even if you already know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I was a little bit fast in asking SO. I have found the answer myself:

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET [PKFIELD]="Au1" WHERE StrComp([PKFIELD],'Au', 0) = 0
```

Comment: Your WHERE clause would be more efficient if it were: `WHERE PKFIELD Like 'Au*' AND StrComp([PKFIELD],'Au', 0) = 0`. The reason is because the first condition will use the index to reduce the number of records being compared with StrComp(). Without it, it will have to run StrComp() on every row.