# How to run a case sensative comparison on text fields Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to run a query to remove a set of ID's from a table when they are present in a field from another table.

The problem is both ID fields are of type text and the search does not appear to be case sensitive (but I need it to be). (i.e. ABC123 is different than abc123)

I am running a query similar to Select myID from table1 where myID NOT IN (Select otherID from table2)

What modification do I need to make in my Access query to make the results case sensitive when running comparison?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745648/case-sensitive-where-in-access-2010

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM table1  a LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.myID = b.otherID
WHERE   StrComp(IIF(IsNull(b.otherID ), a.myID , b.otherID), a.myID, 0) <> 0 
OR IsNull(b.otherID)
```